# Xcode: didUpdateLocations not called but location manager is updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am facing very strange issue.Location manager delegate method is not being called but if I check `_locManager.location` then it gives me updated location.

PS: `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` is mentioned in plist.

Also I am calling `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` as well.

Here is the Location Manager setup code as requested.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            _locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

            _locManager.delegate = self;

            _locManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

            _locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

            _locManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;

            if ([_locManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
            {
                [_locManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            }
            if ([_locManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)])
            {
                self.locManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates =YES;
            }
            _locManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=YES;

        });
```

Comment: Show code (where do you setup the delegate).

Comment: please add this key also into plist file NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Comment: @JeckyModi why should I do that ?Any specific reasons?

Comment: Location When In Use

Comment: @DesertRose please check here for reason https://gist.github.com/benbahrenburg/c4c992c8c61d197510ea

Comment: It should also be noted that **locationManager:didFailWithError:** will run if the location is not set in the simulator, as you'd expect.

Comment: @JeckyModi I am using NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription already.So there is no need to use NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.

Comment: @AntonyRaphel Its on real device not on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your location manager from the `async` block as it is already async. Also, if you keep it in the async block, its delegates will be called back in that thread.